# lcurl: upload file using HTTP multipart/formdata

Tags: http, lua, multipartform-data

I use `lcurl` to upload different files (images, docs, exes etc.) to a server. File uploading should be done using `HTTP multipart/formdata` which must contain the file name and its content. Using [lcurl documentation](https://lua-curl.github.io/lcurl/modules/lcurl.html#Class_httpform) I've written the following code(to send an image):

```
curl.easy()
 :setopt_url(serverUrl)
 :setopt_httppost(curl.form()
             :add_file('file', filePath, 'image/png', fName,
                   {'Content-length: ' .. fSize}
         ))
 :setopt_postfields('apikey=' .. apikey)
 :perform()
 :close()
```

The server is responding that `POST request contains no file field`.

What is not correct in the example code? What is missing?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Using `:setopt_postfields` to add `apikey` rewrote `file` field.

Here is a sketch that worked well:

```
curl.easy()
 :setopt_url(url)
 :setopt_httppost(curl.form()
             :add_content('apikey', apikey, 'text/plain')
             :add_file('file', filePath, 'application/octet-stream',
                   fName, {'Content-length: ' .. fSize}
         ))
 :perform()
 :close()
```